# yum update shows three exclamation marks

Tags: centos, yum, repository, gpg, gitlab

```
yum update

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
gitlab_gitlab-ce/x86_64/signature              |  836 B  00:00:00
gitlab_gitlab-ce/x86_64/signature              | 1.0 kB  00:00:00 !!!
gitlab_gitlab-ce-source/signature              |  836 B  00:00:00
gitlab_gitlab-ce-source/signature              |  951 B  00:00:00 !!!
No packages marked for update
```

I'm posting this question as I could not find an answer to following questions:

1) I'm assuming the entries are related to checking the signature for the gpg, which is defined in the .repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d

The repo file was created during the default installation of a GitLab environment. I've seen this exact output in other posts as well, but they didn't mention the phenomenon at all.

Why are there multiple entries for the two repositories?

2) What is the meaning of the three exclamation marks behind the second entry for each repository?

The closest I could find for this question was this https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/8c7u80/why_are_there_two_signature_entries_for_some/
but it does not really address the problem in my opinion.

Comment: Which distribution and release are you are on?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 CentOS 7.5.1804

Comment: I can reproduce the same behavior for the base repo by adding `repo_gpgcheck=1` to the `[base]` stanza of `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`. I don't understand what it means, though.

Answer (score 5):

It means the setting for checking the GPG signature is off and no check is being made to verify downloaded package's authenticity.

For example in the Gitlab repo file located in:
`/etc/yum.repos.d/gitlab_gitlab-ee.repo`

Value is
`gpgcheck=0`

You can get rid of this by installing the GPG key from Gitlab's servers and setting the value to 1. The instructions to do so, in Gitlab's case, are here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/update/package_signatures#package-repository-metadata-signing-keys

As a sidenote, `gpgcheck` should not be mixed up with the `repo_gpgcheck` setting which enables signature verification of the *yum repository metadata*, not the packages themselves.

Answer (score 1):

My environment is Centos 7.6 and I have the same situation.

I checked the output of `yum repolist -v`.

And I found that the `Repo-exire` of `gitlab_gitlab-ce/x86_64` and `gitlab_gitlab-ce-source` is `300 second(s)`. On the other hand, the others are `21,600 second(s)`.

```
Repo-id      : extras/7/x86_64
Repo-name    : CentOS-7 - Extras
Repo-revision: 1544457521
Repo-updated : Tue Dec 11 01:00:03 2018
Repo-pkgs    : 321
Repo-size    : 392 M
Repo-mirrors : http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=extras&infra=stock
Repo-baseurl : http://ftp.neowiz.com/centos/7.6.1810/extras/x86_64/ (9 more)
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Thu Jan 24 11:56:00 2019)
  Filter     : read-only:present
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

Repo-id      : gitlab_gitlab-ce/x86_64
Repo-name    : gitlab_gitlab-ce
Repo-updated : Tue Jan 22 23:20:38 2019
Repo-pkgs    : 437
Repo-size    : 141 G
Repo-baseurl : https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/el/7/x86_64/
Repo-expire  : 300 second(s) (last: Thu Jan 24 13:11:16 2019)
  Filter     : read-only:present
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.repo
```

I guess "!!!" means the repo information is expired.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I have a repo that shows the `Repo-expire` value of `21,600 second(s)` but it shows 2 signature lines and the latter signature line shows `!!!` as described by the original poster.